# ListView.setSelectionFromTop() not working

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView populated by a string-array. I want to select an item dynamically but .setSelection(1) and .setSelectionFromTop(1,100) does not work.

```
list.setSelection(2);
Log.i(TAG, "my pos: "+ list.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

This traces out "my pos: -1"

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setSelection()` and `getSelectedItemPosition()` refer to two different things.

"Selection" refers to the first visible row, as in `getFirstVisiblePosition()`.
"Selected" refers to a selected View, as in `View#setSelected()`.

Which one do you want?

Comment: Looking at the API is states that you pass the position you want to select with setSelection() and getSelectedItemPosition() returns the position of the selected item.  If I select item #2 by passing the position of 2 it stands to reason that the selected item would be at position 2, right?

Comment: Are you referring to ["Sets the currently selected item"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29)? But what about the next sentence "If in touch mode, the item will not be selected but it will still be positioned appropriately."

Comment: If using setSelection the selected item is positioned at the top of the list.  In touch mode the item is positioned but not selected. The use of the word position is what is so confusing, right? You pass a position (int) with setSelection. You get the position (position in list) of the selected item with getSelectedItemPosition. And then they refer to the physical placement of the list item as positioning. 

If we refer to the ListView item position as "index" it's a bit more clear. So setSelection gets passed an index of 2. getSelectedItemPosition returns the index of the selected position.

Comment: My question is why does getSelectedItemPosition return -1 when I know that the selected item is within the list

Comment: But you are still ignoring the fact that the ListView is in touch mode, so `setSelection(index)` is not calling `setSelected()` on the "indexed" row. (I agree this a confusing subject, but try `getFirstVisiblePosition()` with `setSelection()`. It will work as long as the "indexed" row is not too close to the end of the list. If you want a different solution you will need to describe what you want, _not_ what you are doing.)

Comment: Sorry, Sam. I didn't realize that ListView was in touch mode by default. Now I understand what you were saying.

Basically I have a 2 views on top of each other. The top view contains my list and the bottom contains a keypad. The selected items in the list are centered vertically. 

When I hide the keypad parent the list expands to fill the screen. This is where my problem is: I'm trying to use setSelectionFromTop to move the selected item back to the center after my list resizes.

Comment: Before and after the resizing, I can scroll the list and it snaps to the center as expected. The only time is ignores my request to selectFromTop is when I'm calling that function in code after the resize occurs.

Thanks for your patience. I tend to be stubborn when I think I know what I'm talking about :)

Comment: After taking another look at the methods for ListView in the Android Developer API I found the smoothScrollBy method which doesn't require the position. Now when the bottom view is hidden and the list is expanded I simply take the size difference and adjust the list accordingly.

Thanks for your help with this, Sam. I appreciate it.

Comment: "I tend to be stubborn when I think I know what I'm talking about." Ha, me too. I'm glad you found a solution.